# How to show symmetrical negative definite matrix is non singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's have matrix $A = A^T$ and we know $A$ is negative definite, so for any vector $x$ different from zero vector we have $x^T A x < 0$

On wikipedia i found a fact that negative definite matrix has its k-th order leading principal minor negative when k is odd, and positive when k is even.

Also, i know how to prove that $A$ is non singular when $A$ is symmetrical positive definite matrix, is it possible to use this proof maybe?

I'd be really happy for some help about this

Comment: You can easily reduce the proof to the positive-definite case: if $A$ is negative definite, then $-A$ is positive definite, and it is obvious that $A$ is non-singular iff $-A$ is non-singular.

Comment: @bakula i don't believe i just missed easiest thing... thank you so much :)

Comment: It happens all the time, no problem :)